# Fatal error: Cannot declare class ProductFilterIterator, because the name is already in use in

Tags: php, function, class, php-7, filter-iterator

With the help of class ProductFilterIterator want to get data

```
class ProductFilterIterator extends \FilterIterator
{
    protected $filter;
    protected $length;

    public function __construct(\Iterator $iterator,  $filter)
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->length = -strlen($filter);
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }

    public function accept() : bool
    {
        $current = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return substr($current['Товар'], $this->length) == $this->filter;
    }
}


$iterator = (new \ArrayObject($obj['items']))->getIterator();
$filter = new ProductFilterIterator($iterator, $arPart['ARTICLE']);

foreach ($filter as $obj) {
   echo "<pre>";
```

I'm getting an error- Fatal error:  Cannot declare class ProductFilterIterator, because the name is already in use in

Comment: Can you specify framework that you are using?

Comment: Did you read the previous tutorial?
https://blog.floriancourgey.com/2018/05/create-an-admin-for-a-customized-sql-table/

Comment: So if you work without Prestashop you need to integrate Smarty into you system.

Comment: Include dependency https://packagist.org/packages/smarty/smarty
and setup https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installing.smarty.basic.tpl

Comment: It's hard to explain...

Comment: First, you need to configure routes in your system to reach this page /prestashop/my-pasta

Comment: Than you need to bind route to PastaController initContent action

Comment: Than configure your system Service Container to include Smarty engine.
Than it maybe works

Comment: I would recommend you to use modern frameworks like Laravel of Symfony to do this task. It would be much faster

Answer (score 0):

Try using Namespace,

```php
namespace Custom;
class ProductFilterIterator extends \FilterIterator
{
    protected $filter;
    protected $length;

    public function __construct(\Iterator $iterator,  $filter)
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->length = -\strlen($filter);
        parent::__construct($iterator);
    }

    public function accept() : bool
    {
        $current = $this->getInnerIterator()->current();
        return \substr($current['Товар'], $this->length) == $this->filter;
    }
}


$iterator = (new \ArrayObject($obj['items']))->getIterator();
$filter = new ProductFilterIterator($iterator, $arPart['ARTICLE']);

foreach ($filter as $obj) {
   echo "<pre>";
```